# python (3.2) - ftplib & "unicode" file names

Tags: python, ftplib

Situation:
I have small NAS server with FTP, SHH, Samba (and other) protocols. 
I want to make python script which copy files from "source directory" (from desktop PC - Windows 7) to "destination directory" on NAS via FTP.

Problem:
ftp.mkd("André")
makes correct uft-8 directory

1. I cannot open this directory with total commander ftp
2. I cannost open this directory in windows explorer (\198.168.X.Y\destination-directory\Adnré)
3. SSH: ls command shows "André"

Total commander:
When I make same directory "André"

1. Total c. - acceessible
2. windows - accessible
3. SHH: ls command shows "AndrÃ©" (ok, this isnt problem)

Solution:
How I can convert "André" to "AndrÃ©"? What I must do with string before I pass it to ftp.mkdir() ? (script is in utf-8)

Answer (score 0):

## The Problem

This seems to be an issue with Unicode string normalization.

Unicode often allows for the same character to be represented by different underlying binary sequences.  For example, "é" (e-acute) can be represented by the single code point U+00E9 (Latin small e with acute), or by the two code point sequence U+0065 (Latin small e) U+0301 (Combining acute accent).

```py
>>> 'Andr\u00E9'
'André'
>>> 'Andr\u0065\u0301'
'André'
```

They look the same, and according to the Unicode specification they are both acceptable ways to represent e-acute, but you can peek behind the curtain and see that the binary representation is different.

```py
>>> bytes('Andr\u00E9', 'utf-8')
b'Andr\xc3\xa9'
>>> bytes('Andr\u0065\u0301', 'utf-8')
b'Andre\xcc\x81'
```

## The Solution

You need to normalize the underlying representation.  Unicode provides four different [Normalization Forms](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Norm_Forms): NFD, NFC, NFKD, and NFKC.

The D forms decompose characters into their multiple code point forms, and the C forms compose them into their single code point forms.

The K stands for compatibility (because C is already being used to stand for composition).  The K forms will decompose ligatures into their individual characters, so you almost certainly want to use a K form (though it doesn't seem to make a difference for your "André" example).

As for the choice between C and D forms, recall the binary output we saw earlier when using the composed, single-code-point form for e-acute:

```py
>>> bytes('Andr\u00E9', 'utf-8')
b'Andr\xc3\xa9'
```

and note that U+00C3 = Ã and U+00A9 = ©

It should still display as "André" and not "AndrÃ©", but that's a separate issue with software that either isn't Unicode aware or that has its encoding settings misconfigured.

The important takeaway is that if you want the "AndrÃ©" behavior, you should normalize using a C form.

In short, normalize using NFKC form.

## The Code

To do this in Python, use [`unicodedata.normalize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize):

```py
>>> from unicodedata import normalize
>>>
>>> bytes(normalize('NFKC', 'Andr\u00E9'), 'utf-8')
b'Andr\xc3\xa9'
>>> bytes(normalize('NFKC', 'Andr\u0065\u0301'), 'utf-8')
b'Andr\xc3\xa9'
```

or, in your case:

```py
from unicodedata import normalize

ftp.mkd(normalize('NFKC', 'André'))
```